# some coordinates that I extracted from geocoder in Python are not saving in the variable I created

Tags: python, pandas, geocode, geopy

`enter code here`Hi,
I want to save some coordinates(latitude and longitudes) I extracted through geocodes, the problem I have is those coordinates are not saving and I can't seem to add them as columns to the table I generated using pandas

I get this error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude'

```
    import pandas
    from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
    df1= pandas.read_json("supermarkets.json")
    nom= Nominatim(scheme= 'http')
    lis= list(df1.index)
    for i in lis:

        l= nom.geocode(list(df1.loc[i,"Address":"Country"]))
        j=[]+ [l.latitude]
        k=[]+ [l.longitude]
```

I expect a way to get save the coordinates and include them in my table. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`nom.geocode(..)`** [geopy-doc]](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.geocoders.Nominatim.geocode) can result in a `None` given the address can not be found, or the query is not answered in sufficient time. This is specified in the documentation:

> **Return type:**
>
> `None`, `geopy.location.Location` or a `list` of them, if `exactly_one=False`.

```
from operator import attrgetter

locations = df['Address':'Country'].apply(
    lambda r: nom.geocode(list(r)), axis=1
)
nonnull = locations.notnull()
df.loc[nonnull, 'longitude'] = locations[nonnull].apply(attrgetter('longitude'))
df.loc[nonnull, 'latitude'] = locations[nonnull].apply(attrgetter('latitude'))
```

We this first query all locations, and next we check what has been succesfull, and retrieve the `latitude`, and `latitude` for that location.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used iloc[] instead of df['Address':'Country'], I changed it because I was getting an error: something about not being able to slice str object. I don't understand some of what you did but I'll go back and study. Thanks once again.